# SQL in Java. Cannot receive the result set

Tags: java, sql

I hope that you can correct me if my syntax is wrong. I could check on Google only if the SELECT...WHERE clause is correct.

I want to retrieve the **student_id** for using it in another query, but seems that all I get from this is a "0".

in java file:

```
rst = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT student_id FROM students WHERE name= 'to_delete'");
sid = rst.getInt("student_id");
```

**to_delete** is a String which this java file receives as a parameter to the method which must return **student_id**. It really contains the correct string(I checked it).

Table "students" contains the fileds: student_id, name, year. I need to have returned the student_id for the name "to_delete".

I have no errors/exceptions, just that when I display the result, I see id: 0 no matter what name I type. Maybe rst.getString("column_name") is correct only for executeUpdate(...)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `next()` on the resultset before you try to get anything out of it. You iterate through the ResultSet by calling the next method every time you want to read a row. When next returns false you're done.

Here's the API documentation for the next method:

> boolean next()
>                throws SQLException
>
> Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position. A
>   ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the
>   first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the
>   second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.
>
> When a call to the next method returns false, the cursor is positioned
>   after the last row. Any invocation of a ResultSet method which
>   requires a current row will result in a SQLException being thrown. If
>   the result set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, it is vendor specified
>   whether their JDBC driver implementation will return false or throw an
>   SQLException on a subsequent call to next.
>
> If an input stream is open for the current row, a call to the method
>   next will implicitly close it. A ResultSet object's warning chain is
>   cleared when a new row is read.
>
> Returns:
>       true if the new current row is valid; false if there are no more rows Throws:
>       SQLException - if a database access error occurs or this method is called on a closed result set

Comment: Just to expand on that a little, the value returned from the query is a result set, which you can think of as a collection.  You have to iterate through the collection one row at a time.  So next() will get a row, and *then* you can get column values from the row.

Comment: @dj_segfault: except keeping in mind the resultSet isn't really a collection, it's more like a wrapper around a database cursor.

Comment: Yeah, I realize what I wrote could be taken that way.  It's better to think of it as an iterator than a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.the problem is you should call next() before you try to get from it.Otherwise you did not get any error but No results.